# Flutter BLoC in a ListView (Firebase Auth)

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc

I want to create a Firebase auth. I want to have the SignUp and Login screen in a ListView. Here I found a issue, I have no idea how to solve it: When I press SignIn it seems like he executes the repository two times. E.g. I write the wrong password, I get two Loading indicators and two times the error snackbar with "Wrong Password". So the state "Loading" and the State "AuthError" gets executed:
Class Auth_State:

```
class AuthError extends AuthState {
  final String error;

  AuthError(this.error);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [error];
}
```

I tried it without BLoC and it worked and tried it without a Listview, only the SignIn window and it worked. So the issue is with bloc:
My Listener :

```
 BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is Authenticated) {
            // Navigating to the dashboard screen if the user is authenticated
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Dashboard()));
          }
          if (state is AuthError) {
            // Showing the error message if the user has entered invalid credentials
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(state.error)));
          }
        },
        child: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
```

and my repos:

```
  Future<void> signIn({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        throw Exception('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        throw Exception('Wrong password provided for that user.');
      }
    }
  }
```

in my main is nothing special, I just provided RepositoryProvider, the BlocProvider and a Streambuilder. Can you tell me what I do wrong? Do I have to add the BlocProvider to my listview or something like that?

(listview:

```
body: Container(
          height: 900,
          width: 400,
          child: ListView(
            children:const [ SignIn(), SignUp()],
          ),
        ));
```

I hope someone of you can help me here :-(

Comment: Instead of using `BlocListener` and `BlocBuilder` in cascade, just use a `BlocConsumer` which is the junction of the two, in the listerner it is interesting to add the `listenWhen`, to call the listerner only when a specific state changes, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: what condition shall I add for the listenWhen? p, c => ... ?

Comment: try `listenWhen: (prev, current) => current is Authenticated  || current is 
 AuthError `.

Comment: dosent work for me :( I solved it without BLoC

Comment: @FabianM, I think your code structure is a bit off, you do need to use BlocBuilder as a direct child of BlocListener of the same bloc. That's why it is triggering two times. Remove the BlocBuilder wrapper from its child & then it should work as expected.